# Exit animation for children items not working in Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion, react-animations

I am making a hamburger menu animation in React using Framer Motion. When I click on the hamburger menu, the side drawer and the navigation items slide in from the left.
[image]

When I click on the close menu icon, then the whole side drawer slides out to the left(which means the exit prop on SideDrawer component is working).

**What do I want?**
When I click on the close icon, I want the navigation items to slide out first and then the side drawer. I have tried adding exit prop to children navigation items. But it does not work.

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Code snippets are as below:

**src/App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Menu from "./components/Menu";
import SideDrawer from "./components/SideDrawer";
import Overlay from "./components/Overlay";

const App = () => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleMenuClick = () => {
    setMenuOpen(!menuOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Menu menuOpen={menuOpen} onMenuClick={handleMenuClick} />
      <SideDrawer menuOpen={menuOpen} />
      <Overlay menuOpen={menuOpen} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**src/components/Menu.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const lineOneVariants = {
  initial: { rotate: "0deg" },
  animate: { y: ".8rem", rotate: "45deg", transformOrigin: "center center" },
};
const lineTwoVariants = {
  initial: { opacity: 1 },
  animate: { opacity: 0 },
};
const lineThreeVariants = {
  initial: { rotate: "0deg" },
  animate: { y: "-.8rem", rotate: "-45deg", transformOrigin: "center center" },
};

const Menu = ({ onMenuClick, menuOpen }) => {
  return (
    <div className="hamburger_menu">
      <div className="hamburger_menu-line-container" onClick={onMenuClick}>
        <motion.div
          variants={lineOneVariants}
          initial="initial"
          animate={menuOpen ? "animate" : "initial"}
          className="hamburger_menu-line-1"
        ></motion.div>
        <motion.div
          variants={lineTwoVariants}
          initial="initial"
          animate={menuOpen ? "animate" : "initial"}
          className="hamburger_menu-line-2"
        ></motion.div>
        <motion.div
          variants={lineThreeVariants}
          initial="initial"
          animate={menuOpen ? "animate" : "initial"}
          className="hamburger_menu-line-3"
        ></motion.div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

**src/components/Overlay.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const overlayVariants = {
  initial: { opacity: 0 },
  animate: { opacity: 1 },
};

const Overlay = ({ menuOpen }) => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={overlayVariants}
      initial="initial"
      animate={menuOpen ? "animate" : "initial"}
      className="overlay"
    ></motion.div>
  );
};

export default Overlay;
```

**src/components/SideDrawer.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

const drawerVariants = {
  initial: {
    x: "-100vw",
    opacity: 0,
  },
  animate: {
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      type: "linear",
      ease: "easeInOut",
      staggerChildren: 0.1,
      delayChildren: 0.15,
    },
  },
};

const drawerMenuVariants = {
  initial: { x: "-5rem", opacity: 0 },
  animate: {
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      type: "linear",
      ease: "easeInOut",
    },
  },
};

const SideDrawer = ({ menuOpen }) => {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      {menuOpen && (
        <motion.div
          variants={drawerVariants}
          initial="initial"
          animate="animate"
          exit="initial"
          className="sideDrawer"
        >
          <nav className="sideDrawer-menu">
            <ul>
              <motion.li
                variants={drawerMenuVariants}
                whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
              >
                <a href="#">Register/Login</a>
              </motion.li>
              <motion.li
                variants={drawerMenuVariants}
                whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
              >
                <a href="#">About</a>
              </motion.li>
              <motion.li
                variants={drawerMenuVariants}
                whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
              >
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
              </motion.li>
              <motion.li
                variants={drawerMenuVariants}
                whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
              >
                <a href="#">CV</a>
              </motion.li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the side drawer to wait until the exit animation for the children finishes before starting its own exit animation.

You can do this by using the `when` property of the `transition`. See [Orchestration](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animation/#orchestration) in the docs.

In your case, you'd add it to the `initial` variant of your `drawerVariants`, since that's the variant you animate to on exit:

```
initial: {
  x: "-100vw",
  opacity: 0,
  transition: {
    when: "afterChildren"
  }
},
```

You probably also want to add some staggering and easing there if you want to mirror the animate *in* behavior, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670537/how-to-fix-hamburger-menu-animation   Thanks