# How to fix hamburger menu animation?

Tags: css, reactjs, mern, hamburger-menu, framer-motion

I have added hamburger menu to my web application (MERN stack) for screen sizes below 500 px.

[image]

When I click on the hamburger menu, both the lines should animate to a cross, which is happening. However, the two menu lines remain on the screen as well. Why is it happening?

[image]

I am using framer motion for menu animation.
**GITHUB REPO: https://github.com/sundaray/hamburger_menu**

Comment: can you show the code for the hamburgers section

Comment: Pls. check out the github repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two Hamburger components in your app. One in `App.js` and one in `Header.js`.